# finstr - Unable to get statements

Tags: r, financial, xbrl

I am working with an XBRL document filed by an Indian company at India. The documents can be downloaded for a small fee from the [Ministry of Corporate Affairs](http://mca.gov.in/) website. The `xbrl_get_statements()` function fails as shown below.

```
# Get annual report XBRL and extract statements
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
org2015Inst <- INST #the XML file from MCA website
org2015 <- xbrlDoAll(org2015Inst,cache.dir = "XBRLCache", prefix.out="out", verbose = TRUE)
org2015Stmts <- xbrl_get_statements(org2015)
```

And, this is the error I get.

```
> org2015Stmts <- xbrl_get_statements(org2015)
Error: incorrect length (0), expecting: 965
```

Can you please help?